# ARC is turned off and Analyzer is showing denials for class methods

Tags: iphone, ios6

```
+ (Photo *)photoWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
return [[Photo alloc] initWithImage:image] ;// Potential leak of an object

}
```

Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
Object leaked: allocated object is returned from a method whose name (photoWithImage) does not start with copy, mutableCopy, alloc or new

```
+ (Photo *)photoWithFilePath:(NSString *)path {
return [[Photo alloc] initWithFilePath:path];
}// potential leak of an object
```

Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
Object leaked: allocated object is returned from a method whose name (photoWithFilePath) does not start with copy, mutableCopy, alloc or new

Is there anyother way of fixing it if dont want to use autorelease.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you are not following the conventions. You must adjust to follow the conventions. Since you don't want to autorelease the returned objects, you can rename these methods to start with new (`newPhotoWithImage` and `newPhotoWithPath`).

You don't say why you don't want to return autoreleased objects. Maybe if you elaborate on those reasons we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: because now i m using ARC and it releases and autoreleases automatically